# How to fetch the values from alertview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I am creating a custom alert view and `textfield` also included in `alertview`.

How to give the values in `textfield` and how to get those values you already assigned?

Comment: check this (http://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html)

Comment: The `UIAlertView` is deprecated now. You should use `UIAlertController` now, as mentioned by @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani

Comment: the question is related to iOS 6 or below not above so alert view is working perfectly

Comment: link contains `UIAlertView` as well `UIAlertController `.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom Delegate method. 
Declare your delegate method in custom Alert class and pass the data with it.

In Alert View Class

```
Alert.h

@protocol AlertDelegate
- (void) setTxtValue:(NSSTring *)txtVal;

@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) <id> AlertDelegate *delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSTring *getTxtVal;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITextField *txtFld;



 Alert.m
-(Void)viewDidLoad
{
  txtFld.text = getTxtVal;
}
```

On Ok Button Call your delegate Method

```
-(void)OkClicked
{
    [self.delegate setTxtValue: txtFld.text];
}
```

Call Alert Class from any View Controller

```
-(void)showAlert
{
  Alert *alertObj = [[Alert alloc]init];
  alertObj.delegate = self;
}

- (void) setTxtValue:(NSSTring *)txtVal
{
  NSLog(@"entered Val: %@", txtVal);

}
```

Hope This Helps you.